# Scala Play framework 2.1 derived classes

Tags: scala, polymorphism, playframework-2.1

I'd like to produce JSON for a List that includes both base classes and derived classes.  The code below only produces JSON for the Animal class (I do not get the breed field for the Dog type members).  Some help would be appreciated.

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

class Animal (val name:String) {
}

object Animal {
  implicit object animalWrite extends Writes[Animal] {
    def writes(ts: Animal) = JsObject(Seq("name" -> JsString(ts.name)))
  }
}

case class Dog (override val name:String, val breed: String) 
    extends Animal(name)  {
}

object Dog {
    implicit val format = Json.format[Dog]
}

case class Cat (override val name:String, val hairLength: Int) 
    extends Animal(name)  {
}

object Cat {
    implicit val format = Json.format[Cat]
}

object helloWorld extends App {
//  The list below outputs:     [{"name":"Ruff","breed":"labrador"}]
//  val l = List[Dog](Dog("Ruff", "labrador"))

//  The list below outputs:     [{"name":"Ruff"},{"name":"Fluffy"}]
//  I expect to see: [{"name":"Ruff","breed":"labrador"},{"name":"Fluffy","hairLength":3}]
    val l = List[Animal](Dog("Ruff", "labrador"), Cat("Fluffy", 3))
    println(Json.toJson(l))
}
```

Scala and Play newbie here, please excuse inappropriate use of terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The json API extensively uses implicit parameters which is a feature of Scala where you can provide an "implicit" parameter list and if you don't specify those parameters the compiler will try to find an object in the current scope that is marked as implicit and matches that signature.

So if you for example would write:

```
implicit val s = "my implicit string"

def magicPrint(implicit message: String) { println(message) }

// and then call it
magicPrint
```

The compiler would select s for the parameter message since it is in scope and has the correct type (`String`), so after the implicit resolution the last line of code would actually look more like this

```
magicPrint(s)
```

The Format/Writer is selected by the compiler, at compile time, with an implicit parameter. If you look at the signature of the method, `toJson[A](item: A)(implicit writes: Writes[A])`, it takes an implicit `Writes[A]` which in your case is a `Writes[List[Animal]]` since `List[Animal]` is the type of your list `l`. Play contains a default has a writer that takes care of the collection (`DefaultWrites.traversableWrites`) which in turn takes an implicit `Writes[A]` - in your case `Writes[Animal]`, so the compiler will select and pass your animalWrites.

That your list contains different types of animals is something that happens at runtime and the compiler has no way of knowing that from the type information available at your `Json.toJson(l)`

So, as you see you cannot achieve what you want in the way you thought, but you can do it in almost the same way by letting the animal writer know about the subtypes, for example:

```
implicit object animalWrite extends Writes[Animal] {
  def writes(ts: Animal) = ts match {
    // this will get an implicit Writes[Dog] since d is a Dog
    case d: Dog => Json.toJson(d) 
    // this will get an implicit Writes[Cat] since c is a Cat
    case c: Cat => Json.toJson(c) 
    case x => throw new RuntimeException(s"Unknown animal $x")
  }
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks johanandren.  That's helpful, I figured the issue had to do with implicits but I didn't understand how.  What I did to workaround the situation was to implement a serialize method in Dog and Cat that calls `Json.toJson(this)` and to call it with `l.map(_.serialize).mkString("[", ",", "]")`.  Yours is better since you didn't have to manually concatenate the Json together like I did. Thanks.

Comment: Is'nt better to add a function toJson in animal witch could be implemented like that 

```
    case class Dog (override val name:String, val breed: String) 
        extends Animal(name)  {
        def toJson = Json.toJson(this)     
    }

```

Comment: Usually doing it like that is avoided since it would mix and tightly couple your domain model with the implementation details of one form of serialization while type classes which play json typically uses nicely decouples this.