# Json serialization of complex list

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play Framework 2.1.3 I am trying to write json serialization which would work with following classes:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional._

trait Task
case class TaskA(id: Int, options: String) extends Task
case class TaskB(id: Int, name: String, options: String) extends Task
case class TaskC(id: Int, mapping: Map[String, Int], options: String) extends Task

case class TasksQueue(qid: Int, queue: List[Task])
```

Of course I can easily create serialization for individual case classes extending `Task` e.g. with `implicit val fmt = Json.format[TaskA]` etc. but I have no idea how to implement this for `TasksQueue`.

The difficult part is that I want to be able to put different types of tasks in `queue` value of `TasksQueue`. Is there any way of adding type parameters to the Task which would not limit the type of task that I put on that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout my reply to this question which answers the same kind of problem:

[Scala Play framework 2.1 derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645830/scala-play-framework-2-1-derived-classes/17733064#17733064)